# iphone - manipulating movies

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ipad

Is there a way to manipulate movies in iphone in a way I can have, for example, the exact timecode in realtime of a movie being played? or the timecode of a movie being scrubbed?

And, btw, there's a way to scrub a video like the video edit mode of iPhone 3GS?

Can you guys pinpoint me a way to follow, if any?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this with existing API. It's possibly coming in a future release (check the release notes for the current beta for example).